JTAPI error "Unable to create provider -- user connected on an invalid port
I have a CUCM 14 running,  my developer colleague could not connect to the JTAPI account from his app, gets the error JTAPI error "Unable to create provider -- user connected on an invalid port. If I deliberately enter the wrong password I get the bad password error. I have created another application user account and get the same issue.
I then tested the JTAPI tool against another lab CUCM 14 in non-secure mode and its fine.
What am I missing.
Any assistance would be most appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
I then tested the JTAPI tool against another lab CUCM 14 in non-secure mode and its fine.

CUCM CTI Manager supports JTAPI secure and insecure connections (by far the more commonly used) on separate ports.  If the CUCM JTAPI user is a member of the Standard CTI Secure Connection access control group, CTI Manager will expect (and require) a connection via the secure port.
If the JTAPI app/client is using the default insecure connection mode, it is likely trying to connect to the insecure connection port and getting refused.  You may need to remove the Standard CTI Secure Connection role from the user.

It's worked, thanks, I removed the Standard CTI Secure Connection and the JTAPI connected

I want to record the incoming call to the ip phone controlled by  a user either using JTAPI or any other solution, have you any idea how to do that, Thanks

I got the same issue when tried to integrate call recording service with CUCM 14.
Jul 11 09:00:05 ERROR [pool-1-thread-14] cz.zoom.callrec.jtapisniffer20.JTAPIConnectionImpl - Unable to obtain provider: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. Check configuration and CCM status
Jul 11 09:00:10 ERROR [pool-1-thread-14] cz.zoom.callrec.jtapisniffer20.JTAPIConnectionImpl - Exception while getting provider
com.cisco.jtapi.PlatformExceptionImpl: Unable to create provider -- bad login or password.

Tried different ways with no success.
But today i found solution finally.
You have to restart CTI Manager service at CUCM side.
I've also replaced JTAPI version (jtapi.jar can be downloaded from cucm) at my recording server.
https://developer.cisco.com/site/jtapi/documents/jtapi-ucm-compatibility-matrix/

I tried to restart CTI Manager service didn't worked, we don't have the same issue, the JTAPI tool work with a  CUCM 14 in non-secure but didn't worked with a CUCM in secure mode. I noticed also that the CTIManager QBE TLS port 2749 is enabled in the CUCM that didn't worked.
